# Classifications of the indefinite generalized Cartan matrix

Tags: lie-algebras, matrix-theory, lie-theory

I want to know that the present results about classifications of generalized indefinite Cartan matrices.
  I only have known that the classifications of hyperbolic matrces.

Comment: *Cartan* matrix, or really Gartan?

Comment: @LSpice sorry，It's Cartan matrix.